# Shell script with select command to show a list of files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, filename

I've written the attached `bstls.sh` shell script which uses the command select to choose the subfolder or file in a folder passed as argument on which execute the ls command.

```
#! /bin/bash
#Personal version of shell command ls which presents to user the list of files with shell command select
#Usage: bstls.sh folder

#if parameter numbers is different from one, exit
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo -e "Usage:\n\tbstls folder"
    exit 1
fi

PS3='Which element to ls?'
#command sed substitutes blank spaces with £ in file or folder names
#in this way user can select files or folders with blank spaces in between

list="Exit $(ls "$1" | sed 's/ /£/')"
select option in $list
do
    if [ "$option" = "Exit" ] #if user selects Exit, then exit the program
    then
        exit 0
    elif [ -n "$option" ] #if name is valid, shows the files inside
    then
        #reuse sed command to reconvert to original file name
        filename=$(echo "$option" | sed 's/£/ /')
        ls "$1"/"$filename"
    else #if the number of the choice given by user is wrong, exit
        echo "Invalid choice ($REPLY)!"
    fi
done
```

My main problem is how to show file names with spaces in the list of select options.
For example, if I have a folder *temp* with the subfolder *foo* and the file *hello world* inside it, then launching the following

```
./bstls.sh temp
```

should make me select from option

```
1)Exit 
2)foo 
3)hello 
4)world
```

(the last two separated from each other).

Now I go to my real question. I have tried to solve this issue converting blank spaces with the symbol £ with the sed command.

```
list="Exit $(ls "$1" | sed 's/ /£/')"
```

In this way, names with blank spaces can be processed as one by the select command.
I then change again the symbol £ with a blank space when I use ls command.

```
filename=$(echo "$option" | sed 's/£/ /')
```

So now, when launching

```
./bstls.sh temp
```

I get the choices

```
1)Exit 
2)foo
3)hello£world
```

Here is the question (finally): is there a way to output in the selection menu file names without that £ symbol?

Comment: [Parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a *shell glob* instead of `ls`:

```
select option in "Exit" "$1"/*
.
.
.
elif [ -n "$option" ]; then
  ls "$option"
else
.
.
.
```

Comment: Yes! Great! As always I was lost for nothing! Thank a lot @steeldriver it worked!